# Simulate multiple coin toss streak

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to simulate a coin toss sequence and monitor how many attempts I have to do to obtain a streak of heads (or tails) of predetermined length.
In other words, I need to count how many coin tosses I need to have an unbroken streak of 3 heads. Once the script accomplished that streak, it should do the same for a streak of 4 and a streak of 5.

I did try with something like this:

```
def main():
    import random

    attemps = [4, 5, 6]  # length of the streaks we want to achieve
    for item in attemps:
        mylist = list(xrange(item))
        while True:
            for i in mylist:
                y = random.randint(0, 1) # 0 as head, 1 as tail
                print i, y
                if y != 0:
                    return False
```

But of course it doesn't do what I want. It has two problems:

1. It does exit once the coin value is 1, but it does not try again as long as the streak is complete.
2. It tests only the first number of the "attempts" list, that means 4.

I have really no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your function:

```
import random

def main(n):
    """ Returns number of flips needed 
    to get n heads in a row """
    mylist = ['heads', 'tails']
    cnt = 0
    while 1:
        if [random.choice(mylist) for _ in range(n)].count('heads') == n:
            return cnt
        else:
            cnt += 1
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> for i in range(4, 7):
...     main(i)
... 
12
18
29 # All values are completely random, this just happens to be what I got.
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of 'return False' which will return from the function, try break instead - this will exit the current loop iteration.

```
if y != 0:
     break
```

Comment: Thank you! This way it does try again as i wanted, but I can see from the output that once it accomplish a streak of four '0' it keep on looping with the first value of the list attemps = [4,5,6].
Any idea how it could stop with that value and switch to the next (i.e. 5).
Thanks again!